# Can Apache Spark repartition the data received from single Kafka partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, partitioning

We have a Kafka topic with multiple partitions and the load is uneven/skewed in each partition. We can't change the partitioning strategy for Kafka.
I am looking for some ways to repartition the data so that the load is equally processed by all the nodes present within the Apache Spark cluster.
Is it possible to repartition the data across all the nodes received from a single Kafka partition?
If yes, is there a way we can do it efficiently as we have to maintain the state stores also while aggregating the data

Comment: Spark's repartition function can be used, yes, for processing, but that wont solve your Kafka consumer's partition assignments

Comment: @OneCricketeer, you mean to say we can use the repartition function provided by spark but the partitions will be processed by the same node where the data has been received?

Comment: You say you only have one partition. Therefore only one Spark executor can read it. But for each batch of records, you can use Spark repartition to distribute to more executors. Main side effect would be losing processing ordering